# No puedo escribir logs a un fichero usando un canal específico con Monolog en Symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony3

Estoy intentando escribir logs en un fichero concreto usando un canal específico en Monolog (llamado encuestas_cloud) dentro de un Comando en Symfony 3.4, pero no consigo hacerlo.

He leído la documentación de Symfony y he buscado por la web y creo que está bien configurado pero me da un error.

El código es:

En config_dev.yml:

```
monolog:

  handlers:
    main:
        type: stream
        path: '%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log'
        level: debug
        channels: ['!event']

  ...
    encuestas_cloud_logger:
        #type: rotating_file
        type: stream
        path: 'D:/web/xampp/htdocs/temp/logs/encuestas_cloud.log'
        level: info
        channels: ['encuestas_cloud']   
        max_files: 10
```

En services.yml

```
services:
  _defaults:
     autowire: true
     autoconfigure: true
     public: false

  AppBundle\Command\EncuestasCloudCommand\:
    resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Command/EncuestasCloudCommand.php'
    arguments: ['@logger']
    public: true
    tags:
        - { name: monolog.logger, channel: encuestas_cloud }
```

El comando es:

```
// src/AppBundle/Command/EncuestasCloudCommand.php
namespace AppBundle\Command;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
...

class EncuestasCloudCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand

{
  private $logger;

  public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
  {
    $this->logger = $logger;
    parent::__construct();
  }

 ...
 protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
 {

    $logger = $this->logger;
    $logger->addInfo('My logger is now ready');
```

Cuando ejecuto el comando obtengo lo siguiente:

> In LoggerChannelPass.php line 98:
>
> Monolog configuration error: The logging channel "encuestas_cloud" assigned to the
>     "encuestas_cloud_logger" handler does not exist.
>
> In ContainerBuilder.php line 1063:
>
> You have requested a non-existent service "monolog.logger.encuestas_cloud".

Si añado en config_dev.yml lo siguiente `channels: ['encuestas_cloud']`:

```
monolog:
  channels: ['encuestas_cloud'] 

  handlers:
    main:
        type: stream
...
```

Deja de dar error pero el log sigue yendo al canal app del fichero general de logs: dev.log

Por favor, ¿podría ayudarme alguien a averiguar que es lo que está mal configurado o qué falta?

¡¡ Muchas gracias !!

Comment: parece que falta en la configuracion del monolog, en el apartado handlers, configurar de alguna manera el uso de encuestas_cloud

Comment: pregunta: por que necesitas un channel? ten en cuenta que los channel son la info que se envia (si es doctrine, console, events...) defines algun tipo en concreto de log, o solo necesitas escribir lo mismo del archivo log al encuestas_cloud.log? si es esto ultimo con quitar la linea `channels: ['encuestas_cloud']    ` deberia ser suficiente...

Comment: Quiero hacer un comando que se ejecute cada día en automático y que me deje un log en un directorio específico con unos mensajes que he definido sobre la ejecución y también había pensado que me enviara un email cuando se produjera algún fallo. Me interesan sólo los mensajes que yo cree para control y que fuera en otro directorio, por eso lo del canal específico.

Answer (score 0):

El problema estaba en que el comando no estaba correctamente definido como un servicio, por lo que Symfony era incapaz de unir el canal al servicio (y por ende al comando).

Me di cuenta porque al ejecutar:

```
php bin/console debug:container
```

el servicio del comando no aparecía.

Así que después de investigar cómo definir un comando como un servicio la configuración funcionó correctamente.

Aquí dejo el código final que funciona por si puede servir de ayuda a alguien:

En config_dev.yml:

```
monolog:
  channels: ['encuestas_cloud']

  handlers:
    main:
        type: stream
        path: '%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log'
        level: debug
        channels: ['!event','!encuestas_cloud']

  ...
    encuestas_cloud_logger:
        type: rotating_file
        path: 'D:/web/xampp/htdocs/temp/logs/encuestas_cloud.log'
        level: info
        channels: ['encuestas_cloud']   
        max_files: 10
```

En services.yml

```
services:
  _defaults:
     autowire: true
     autoconfigure: true
     public: false

  console.command.encuestas_cloud_command:
    class: 'AppBundle\Command\EncuestasCloudCommand'
    arguments: ['@logger']
    public: true
    tags:
        - { name: monolog.logger, channel: encuestas_cloud }
```

El comando:

```
// src/AppBundle/Command/EncuestasCloudCommand.php
namespace AppBundle\Command;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
...

class EncuestasCloudCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand

{
  private $logger;

  public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
  {
    $this->logger = $logger;
    parent::__construct();
  }

 ...
 protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
 {

    $logger = $this->logger;
    $logger->addInfo('My logger is now ready');
```

Ahora el fichero se crea y el log aparece con el canal que he configurado.

Gracias a todos!!!